# how to refresh parent window when new window has been close

Tags: javascript

guys, I want to ask about how to refresh the parent window when a new window has closed. 
I have a page that has one button has a function for opening a new window CTRL+N (not a popup). I want to make a behavior when the new window has closed then the parent page will be refresh. I really don't know how to do that.

the code for rendering new window is like this
`window.open('report_wjm.html','','height=650,width=1200');`

maybe someone can help me. I would appreciate when giving me an example of it.

Comment: Check the `.closed` property of the object returned by `open` in a regular interval.

Comment: @Bergi like this bro?
`if (window.close('report_wjm.html'){ report_all.php.refresh()}` ? 
note: report_wjm.html is the new window and report_all.php is the parent window

Comment: No. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Return_value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed

Comment: @Bergi thx for the link bro. i can make it now. eheheh..